GCP Service Account Impersonation using Terraform
I am trying to impersonate a GCP service account with the following code in provider.tf file
locals {
 terraform_service_account = "svc-gke@projectx-4567.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

provider "google" {
 alias = "impersonation"
 scopes = [
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
 ]
}

data "google_service_account_access_token" "default" {
 provider                   = google.impersonation
 target_service_account     = local.terraform_service_account
 scopes                     = ["userinfo-email", "cloud-platform"]
 lifetime                   = "1200s"
}

provider "google" {
 project        = "projectx-4567"
 access_token   = data.google_service_account_access_token.default.access_token
 request_timeout    = "60s"
}

My Service Account has the following roles
   "roles/container.admin",
    "roles/compute.admin",
    "roles/servicemanagement.admin",
    "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser",

Also the default login has the iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator role
however the service account does seem to have access to the service usage api
Error: Error when reading or editing Project Service : Request List Project Services projectx-4567 returned error: Failed to list enabled services for project projectx-
4567: googleapi: Error 403: Service Usage API has not been used in project 1355341940 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.
com/apis/api/serviceusage.googleapis.com/overview?project=1355341940 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
how to fix this
If I enable the API manually I am able to get a success but I want the serviceaccount to be able to enable the api

You must activate the service usage API on the console on the project before using it by API (with terraform)

Can you try enabling it using terraform:
resource "google_project_service" "serviceusage_api" {
  project            = "projectx-4567"
  service            = "serviceusage.googleapis.com"
  disable_on_destroy = false
}

